# Azure Logic Send email as group with outlook connector

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

We have logic app which sends an email with office 365 outlook connector. Our requirement is to send an email as group from particular email account.

For example:if DEV1@example.com has Send as permissions on email group => Group1@example.com and if DEV1@example.com sends an email as the group, it shouldlook like Group1@example.com group has sent an email.

We have followed the below documentation given and given right permissions, but still it is not working for us.Has anyone faced similar issue? Please guide us on this.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/solutions/allow-members-to-send-as-or-send-on-behalf-of-group?view=o365-worldwide#allow-members-to-send-email-as-a-group

Answer (score 0):

The Send an email action has an optional parameter, From (Send as), which you can add to the action and use your service account's email address as the sender. To add this parameter, follow these steps:

1. In the Send an email action, open the Add a parameter list, and select the From (Send as) parameter.
2. After the parameter appears on the action, enter the service account's email address.

As per the below image you can set the options

[image]

For Complete Information follow [Office365 Connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-office365-outlook#connect-using-other-accounts).

Check Mailbox Permissions on how to set [mailbox permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/add-users/give-mailbox-permissions-to-another-user) to other user.

Comment: is it the same for gmail's send email?